# How to return parent collection based on subcollection document value in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this collection in my Firestore:

```
Collection: Team1
  Document: TeamName
    Subcollection: Notes
    Subcollection: Users    
       Document: user1 => Field: name: "Anna", uid: "someID"
       Document: user2 => Field: name: "John", uid: "someID"
```

Lets imagine a scenario in which there are many Team collections with the schema above. How to return the whole Team collection with JavaScript (so I can access for example Notes) based on the Name field in Document (in Users subcollection) .

I tried this:

```
 var nameRef = db
    .collection('Team1')
    .doc('TeamName')
    .collection('Users')
    .where('name', '==', 'Anna')

const getData => ()=> {
  nameRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data())
      })
    })
}
```

However the code above outputs only the document fields in the User Doc (name, uid).

Answer (score 1):

Your query will only return documents from the `Users` collection. If you also want to show data from the user, you will need to load their document separately. For the `TeamName` user, that'd be:

```
db
  .collection('Team1')
  .doc('TeamName')
  .get()
```

Or alternatively you can determine and get the parent document for the user with:

```
doc.ref.parent.parent.get()
```

---

If you want to search across all teams for users named Anna, you can use a collection group query. This is a special type of query that searches across all collections with a specific name.

```
var nameRef = db
    .collectionGroup('Users')
    .where('name', '==', 'Anna')

const getData => ()=> {
  nameRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data())
      })
    })
}
```

Here again, this only loads users and not their teams yet. But you can use the same `doc.ref.parent.parent.get()` snippet as before to then also find and load the team document for each user.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. When I return the doc.ref.parent.parent.get() I get a promise :__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: t
Df: e {lf: n, _f: e, ff: FirebaseAppImpl, df: e, INTERNAL: {…}, …}
E_: t {path: n}
I_: null
Mf: false
Of: false
kf: n {key: t, version: t, nn: t, Ye: false, hasCommittedMutations: false}
exists: (...)
id: (...)
metadata: (...)
ref: (...)
__proto__: Object   Under the E_ there are the parents. How to save the array to a variable? I tried object restructuring, but it did not work.

Comment: Yes, just like with your initial `get()`, you'll need to add another `.then()` with a function to process the resulting snapshot. Within that function, you could use a `snapshot.docs.forEach` loop to push the data from each doc into a predefined array.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `.data()` method, the retrieved `doc` also has a `.parent` property which contains a CollectionReference - in this case, it'd reference your `Users` collection. That collection also has a `.parent` property that will point to your `TeamName` document. It's parent will point to your `Team1` collection.

Using these parent properties of the documents and collections, you can work your way 'up' the tree to your Team collection upon which you can retrieve its documents.