# can I get the path or reference of the document fetched from Firestore collection group query?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I want to perform collection group query like this, to get all expired messages document in inbox

```
const oneMonthAgo = moment().subtract(1, "month").toDate();

db.collectionGroup("inbox")
.where("createdAt", "<", oneMonthAgo)
.get();
```

the `inbox` is actually a sub-collection in the `users` collection, so the path will be like this:

```
users/{userID}/inbox/{messageID}
```

after I get all the expired messages using that collection group query code above, then I need to delete all those expired messages. to delete the message document, I need to know the path/reference of the document

I can get the messageID from the field in the message document. but I don't know the user ID is, so I don't know the full path / reference to delete that message

```
users/ ?????? /inbox/{messageID}
```

so can I get the userID just from the result of collection group query code above? because I need to delete the message document using this code

```
db.doc(`users/${??????}/inbox/${messageID}`).delete()
```

the code above will return a promise of `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData` . I need to get the path or reference of the document that I get from collection group query.

can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a message document, you can determine the user by walking up the `parent` chain of its reference:

```
const messages = await db.collectionGroup("inbox")
  .where("createdAt", "<", oneMonthAgo)
  .get();
messages.forEach((messageSnapshot) => {
  const messageRef = messageSnapshot.ref;
  const inboxRef = messageRef.parent;
  const userRef = inboxRef.parent;
  console.log(userRef.id); // logs the id of the user document this message is for
});
```

Also see [How to return parent collection based on subcollection document value in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011622/how-to-return-parent-collection-based-on-subcollection-document-value-in-firesto/64011666#64011666)

Comment: To get the full path as a string, you can also use `messageSnapshot.ref.path`